# AngularJS ng-repeat performance improvement

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created a reporting app that runs the MySQL query and returns the data (30k rows) to Angular JS. The data gets loaded to the HTML table quickly if I limit the number of rows but hangs when 30k rows are to be displayed.

HTML Code snippet -

```
<tbody class="tbody-class">
           <tr ng-repeat="patching in main_data_table.message | filter: (!disableFilter || '') && {uaid: searchText}" ng-if="searchText.indexOf(',')==-1">
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.server_name}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.uaid}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.environment}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.is_disruptive}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.is_disruptive}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.tz_name}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.start_time}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.end_time}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.validator_group}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.patching_group}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.patching_criteria}}</td>
                <td class="table-row-text">{{ patching.patching_documentation_link}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Controller Code snippet -

```
patchingApp.controller('patchingController', function ($scope, $state, patchingServices, $timeout) {
'use strict';

   $scope.searchText   = '';
   $scope.main_data_table = patchingServices.getPatchingReport().get();

   function getDownloadName(){
       var d =  new Date();
       var date = d.getDate() + "" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "" + 
                  d.getFullYear();
       var fileName = "patching_" + date + ".csv";  
       return fileName;
   }

   function setDownloadAttribute() {
       var a = document.getElementById("fileLink");
       a.setAttribute("download", getDownloadName())
   }

   var a = document.getElementById("fileLink");
   a.onclick = setDownloadAttribute;

  });


patchingApp.filter('fill', function() {
       return function(input,val) {
           if(val!=''){
              var out=[];
              var filterVal = val.split(",");
            if (filterVal.length > 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < filterVal.length; i++) {
                    for(var j=0;j<input.length;j++){
                        if (input[j].uaid == filterVal[i]) {
                            console.log("filter:"+filterVal[i]);
                            out.push(input[j]);
                            console.log("uaid"+input[j].uaid);
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(out);
                return out;                   
  }}}});
```

Comment: You should consider doing pagination. Per page you can show limited set of rows (say 50), and as user moves to the other page, you can make a new request to fetch next 50 rows for that page.

Comment: Do I need to add an additional button to load more data if I add pagination? @RahulArora

Comment: Some other good practices for ng-repeat: 1) always use `track by` with ng-repeat so when you come back, it does not re-bind the whole data but only binds if there is updated data 2) Dont use filters in the html template, but define that filter in the controller instead and make the filtering happen from there. It will reduce the number of digest loops.

Comment: Sachdeva: Simple pagination like this (https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp). When you click on any page link, it requests new data.

Comment: getting all 30k rows in go is a bad practice. Apply pagination to your data and if you don't want to add an additional button you can consider using ngInfiniteScroll directive which loads new set of data on scroll. Link https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: Thanks @amanpurohit

Comment: I added pagination but that affects the search and download report functionalities. Any other suggestions? @RahulArora

Comment: Pagination affects the download and search functionalities in my case. @amanpurohit

Comment: You might be applying search on the frontend, thats the reason pagination is effecting your search. You should rather send search request to the backend and get filtered data everytime. Treat search as a new query given by user. That is how websites with large data do stuff. For downloading as well, in case you are giving a csv/excel, that request should go to the backend and response should give file (any format base64 etc.) which can be given to user on frontend after conversion. @TanuSachdeva

Comment: I totally agree with @RahulArora , in case of search you should send the query entered by the user to the api and fetch filtered results & for downloading the reports i suggest something like export the result into a .csv using MySQL `OUTFILE` command and save it in your server/S3 (totally depends on you) and then provide this link as a response in your api. You can then use the download attribute of <a> tag to directly save the file on users system. Furthermore, keep on cleaning these files from server/s3 on regular basis to save space.